# How to MAP AWS_IAM Credentials via HTTP Proxy to Actual HTTP EndPoint in API Gateway of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway

I have a http-endpoint - A.

We can call this endpoint via another http-endpoint-B.

So B-->A

We are using AWS API Gateway to do the above. Now - A is AWS_IAM Protected, and B has no protection. So A require x-amz-security-token, AccessKey,SecretKey,X-Amz-Date,Authorization. I used API Gateway's API's Resource feature - Method Request and Integration request to do the appropriate mapping.

[image]

Done various other ways, but at the end I am getting the following error :

{
"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method......"
}

May I know what I am missing here ?, I have already looked on documentation and several other references but didn't find anything appropriate.

Comment: *Now - A is AWS_IAM Protected, ... So A require x-amz-security-token, AccessKey,SecretKey*  What?  There is **no** AWS service that requires you to pass your secret key with a request.  It is a **secret** key.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am using Amazon Cognito (written lambda/auth code around it), that returns the Temporary credentials(x-amz-security-token, AccessKey,SecretKey)  to access the intended resources.

Comment: Ah, yes that does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting indicates that endpoint A is expecting the request to be signed with sigV4.  Currently, API Gateway will only sign the request to the backend integration endpoint when using the "AWS Service Proxy" integration type. This is hidden by default.  When setting up the method, under "Integration Type" click on "Show Advanced".  That makes "AWS Service Proxy" visible.  When you select it, the integration fields change to a new set that is relevant for calling AWS services.  An [example of using the AWS Service Proxy can be found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html).

Note that API Gateway does not currently support calling all AWS services.  More specifically, it does not support calling other API Gateway APIs as integration endpoints.  So, if endpoint A is another API Gateway API, then this won't work.  If you need to call an AWS service that API Gateway does not currently support, then you can work around this by creating a Lambda function to call your endpoint and call the Lambda function from API Gateway.

Comment: Let me work on it and then I will update the status here.

Comment: May you share any example(code snippet) that how we can call the endpoint from Lambda function in Java. I found this : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-sdk-java , but I didn't find any example e.g. how to set a structure with requisite end point values and call ?, Or we should use any standard http library to call the endpoint ?